# While storing data into my SqlLite it returned that my column was not created

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, mobile

I can't seem to find the error on why the column isn't created.

```
public static final String GAME_TABLE = "Game";

public static final String KEY_GAMEID = "_id";
public static final int COL_GAMEID = 0;

public static final String KEY_OPONENT = "opponentTeam";
public static final int COL_OPONENT = 1;

public static final String KEY_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER = "GamePLAYER1";
public static final int COL_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER = 2;

public static final String KEY_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER = "GamePLAYER2";
public static final int COL_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER = 3;

public static final String KEY_FK_GAME = "FKtournament";
public static final int COL_FK_GAME = 4;

public static final String[] ALL_GAME_KEYS = new String[] {
    KEY_GAMEID, KEY_OPONENT, KEY_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER, KEY_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER, KEY_FK_GAME};

     //THIS IS WHERE I CREATE MY TABLE
     // KEY REY_ROWID is from another table

private static final String GAME_TABLE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "create table " + GAME_TABLE 
        + " (" 
        + KEY_GAMEID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_OPONENT + " string not null, "
        + KEY_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER + "string not null, "
        + KEY_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER + "string not null, "
        + KEY_FK_GAME+" INTEGER REFERENCES "+KEY_ROWID
        + ");";


public long insertGAMERow(String opponentTeam, String GamePLAYER1,  String GamePlayer2, int key) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_OPONENT, opponentTeam);
    initialValues.put(KEY_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER, GamePLAYER1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER, GamePlayer2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FK_GAME, key);
    return db.insert(GAME_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Here are the error logs:

```
08-03 06:27:58.279: I/System.out(3580): true true false
08-03 06:27:58.279: I/Database(3580): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table Game has no column named GamePLAYER1
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580): Error inserting opponentTeam=asd GamePLAYER1=asdda asd GamePLAYER2=asd asd FKtournament=1
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Game has no column named GamePLAYER1: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Game(opponentTeam, GamePLAYER1, GamePLAYER2, FKtournament) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at com.example.beachvolleyball.DBAdapter.insertGAMERow(DBAdapter.java:175)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at com.example.beachvolleyball.NewGame$1.onClick(NewGame.java:125)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-03 06:27:58.289: E/Database(3580):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `string` type in sqlite, use `TEXT` instead. Plus there is no space in you column name and its data type:

```
+ KEY_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER + "string not null, "// <------ error, no space in name and datatype
+ KEY_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER + "string not null, "// <------ error, //
```

so end query is like

`create table Game(_id integer primary key autoincreament, opponentTeam string not null GamePlayer1string not null`... See the issue ?

```
private static final String GAME_TABLE_CREATE_SQL = 
    "create table " + GAME_TABLE 
    + " (" 
    + KEY_GAMEID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_OPONENT + " TEXT not null, "
    + KEY_GAME_FIRST_PLAYER + " TEXT not null, "
    + KEY_GAME_SECOND_PLAYER + " TEXT not null, "
    + KEY_FK_GAME+" INTEGER REFERENCES "+KEY_ROWID
    + ");";
```

More detail here : http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't see that! Off course i needed a space! Also thank you for your advice that i must use the correct data type!

Comment: You're welcome, It's always a good idea to print all sqlite queries while developing app. Saves lot of trouble and valuable time ;)